# TCPDF textfield align right

Tags: textfield, tcpdf

Can someone tell me how to right align a textfield using TCPDF?
So, for a textfield like this, which is a numeric, how to I align on the right?

$pdf->TextField('number_of_crews', 20, 5, array('charLimit'=>3,'multiline'=>true, 'lineWidth'=>0, 'borderStyle'=>'none', 'defaultStyle' => array('textFont'=>array('fontWeight'=>'bold'))), array('v' =>
{number_of_crews}));

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code (https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/source-class-TCPDF_STATIC/#653) you set it in the prop array like so:

`$prop = array( 'alignment' => 'right' );`

As it pertains to you code, it would look like this:

```
$pdf->TextField('number_of_crews', 20, 5, array(
  'charLimit'=>3, 
  'multiline'=>true, 
  'lineWidth'=>0, 
  'borderStyle'=>'none', 
  'alignment'=>'right', 
  'defaultStyle' => array(
    'textFont'=>array(
      'fontWeight'=>'bold'
    )
  )
), array('v' => {number_of_crews}));
```